# How can we implement the Linux command `sed` in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, powershell, sed

### What is `sed`?

If you already know what `sed` is, you can skip reading to the next section of this post.

**What is an example of a  `sed` command?**

Suppose that:

- we want to read data from a file named `input.txt`
- `input.txt` contains a lot of English text (e.g. Jane Austin novel)
- We want to replace every occurrence of the string "`cat`" with the string `"dog"`
- we want to leave `input.txt` unmodified, and write the output to a file in the current working directory named `output.txt`

The `sed` command for doing the above looks like this:

```
sed 's/cat/dog/g' input.txt | tee output.txt
```

**Very general description of the `sed` command with no examples**

One of the more popular Linux commands is named `sed`

"***sed***" stands for "***stream editor***"

`sed` has the following properties:

1. a stream of characters is fed into the `sed` machine (such as "hello world")
2. `sed` modifies the text it receives.
3. `sed` sends the modifies text to a stream of output characters.

The output stream is usually an ASCII-encoded text file)

`sed` mostly uses regular expressions to identify text-patterns, and replace them with other text.

#### Platform Independent Requirement

We want to implement `sed` in python.

However, our `sed` implementation should work on computers running an operating system different from Linux.

The following is ***NOT*** acceptable:

```python
import subprocess  
cmd = "sed 's/cat/dog/g' input.txt | tee output.txt".split(" ")  
subprocess.call(cmd)
```

#### My own sad attempt at implementing `sed`

An attempted solution is shown below.

```python
import subprocess
import os
import sys

def sed(stryng, istream=None, ostream=None):
    if sys.platform == "linux":
        subprocess.run(["sed", stryng])        
        subprocess.call(['sed', 's/\"//g', inp], stdout=out_file)
    elif os.name == 'nt':
        # if running Windows
        lead_up = "@ powershell - Command get-content somefile.txt | %{{$_ -replace "
        expression = ""
        replacement = ""
        subprocess.run(lead_up + f"\"\"{expression}\",\"{replacement}\"}}")
    else:
        raise NotImplementedError()
```

Usage:

```python
    in_file  = open("report_new.txt", "r")
    out_file = open("report_new.txt", "w")
    sed("'s/Nick/John/g'", in_file, out_file)
    out_file.close()
    in_file.close()
```

Comment: use python's [re.sub](https://lzone.de/examples/Python%20re.sub) instead of invoking `sed` or `powershell`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Python anyway, you might as well manipulate the file directly. (see also https://askubuntu.com/a/747455) Pseudocode:

```
subject, replacement = split pattern at /
s = read in_file
in s replace each subject with replacement
write s to out_file
```

I'm not familiar with the details of how `sed` interprets patterns; there might be some unexpected behavior there due to switching from sed's Regex dialect to Python's. However, the basic functions should work about the same. However, I think you have already given up on perfectly consistent behavior, because you assume Powershell's equivalent will perform identically to `sed`.

If you want actual `sed` to do the replacement, I would look into using the Windows Linux Subsystem. Obviously this requires the user to have WLS installed.